Stop an animation and prevent finished event from firing
In .NET MAUI I am creating an animation to change the size of an element inside an AbsoluteLayout, I create the animation like so :
_animationProgress = new Animation(v => AbsoluteContainer.SetLayoutBounds(RectangleProgress, new Rect() { Height = 1, Width = v}), 0, 1);
_animationProgress.Commit(
    this,
    "TrackListSideBarAnimation",
    16,
    DurationMs,
    Easing.Linear,
    OnProgressComplete);

The user can stop the animation at any time and I don't want the OnProgressComplete to fire then. I tried to clean the animation in different way but the OnProgressComplete keep firing, what I tried :
public void Stop()
{
    if (_animationProgression != null)
    {
        _animationProgress.Finished = null;
        _animationProgress.Pause();
        _animationProgress.RemoveFromParent();
        _animationProgress.Dispose();
        _animationProgress = null;
    }
}

I can still ignore the call inside OnProgressComplete if _animationProgress  is null but the fact that the event is still up even after Dispose seems pretty strange. Is it supposed to be like that ? Is there a way to clean entirely an animation after a commit ?

Have you tried using the CancelAnimations extension method for this?
YourView. CancelAnimations();

@FreakyAli I found it thanks to you ! CancelAnimations call view.AbortAnimation for all standard animations (TranslateTo, RotateTo, ...) so view.AbortAnimation did the trick for me

You can call view.AbortAnimation(animationName) to cancel an animation, it will still fire the finished event. So I made the following changes :
    _animationProgress.Commit(
        RectangleProgress, // Pass the element I am animating on
        "TrackListSideBarAnimation",
        16,
        DureeMillisecondes,
        Easing.Linear,
        OnProgressComplete);

Then to stop the animation :
    if (_animationProgress != null)
    {
        _animationProgress.Dispose();
        _animationProgress = null;
        RectangleProgress.AbortAnimation("TrackListSideBarAnimation"); 
    }

Which will call OnProgressComplete where I am handling things like that :
private void OnProgressComplete(double v, bool c)
{
    if (_animationProgress != null)
    {
        ProgressionFinished?.Invoke();
        _animationProgress = null;
    }
}

Pretty strange that you can't do that from the animation though.
